# Local.xml Not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I am new to magento and following tutorials, but i am stuck while trying to use layout.xml, it seems like it is not removing items which i mentioned.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
            <remove name="page_content_heading" />
            <remove name="global_notices" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

My file structure is as following,

```
app
--frontend
----boot (theme name)
------layout (local.xml reside here)
------templates
```

---

```
skin
--frontend
----boot (theme name)
------css
------js
```

Not even my `<action>` tag would work while i add js or css. Am i doing something wrong?

Edit: I cleared the cache, disable it and even delete my browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A theme has to be structured as "package/theme".

So instead of `app/frontend/boot` and `skin/frontend/boot` it should be `app/frontend/boot/default` and `skin/frontend/boot/default`

Then to use the theme, configure "boot" as package and "default" as theme.

Answer (score -1):

Your xml looks ok and its working on my setup. as you says you already tried with disable the cache and all. i think you are placing this file on wrong location. this should be as app/design/frontend/(package_name)/(theme_name)/layout/**local.xml** not layout.xml. in default magento setup package name is rwd and theme name is default.Hope this will help, let me know if you required more information.

Comment: @Ashih While i was able to make it work but bootstrap is not working.